# Uncaught ReflectionException: Class request does not exist in Jenkins

Tags: php, laravel, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I have jenkins up and running on a laravel project. It was working normally till some days ago, then some weird error started to pop up.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class request does not exist in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test_fix_changing-jenkinsfile/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:809
```

I did some digging on the internet, i have cleaned and `chmod 777` into my `bootstrap/cache` folder also checked my `CreatesApplication.php` to make sure i'm importing Kernel from the right place `use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;` everyting seams normal to me. This error show regardless if all tests passes or fail and this is only happening inside jenkins.

I'm using Laravel version 7.30 here's my jenkis file.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
    environment {
    GIT_COMMIT_SHORT = "a${env.GIT_COMMIT.take(7)}"
    DB_DATABASE_AUX = "a${env.GIT_COMMIT.take(7)}"
  }
  stages {
    stage("Build") {
      steps {
        sh 'cp ../.env .'
        sh 'php --version'
        sh 'composer install'
        sh 'composer --version'
        sh 'composer dump-autoload'
        sh 'php artisan key:generate'
      }
    }
    stage('Test backend') {
      steps {
          sh '/usr/bin/php artisan mysql:createdb $GIT_COMMIT_SHORT'
          sh '/usr/bin/php artisan clear-compiled'
          sh '/usr/bin/php artisan optimize'
          sh '/usr/bin/php artisan route:clear'
          sh '/usr/bin/php artisan view:clear'
          sh '/usr/bin/php artisan cache:clear'
          sh 'echo ""DB_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE_AUX}>> .env'
          sh 'chmod 777 bootstrap/cache'
          sh '/usr/bin/php artisan config:cache'
          sh '/usr/bin/php artisan config:clear'
          sh '/usr/bin/php artisan optimize:clear'
          sh '/usr/bin/php artisan migrate:fresh'
          sh '/usr/bin/php artisan passport:install'
          sh '/usr/bin/php vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Unit/ --stop-on-failure'
          sh '/usr/bin/php vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Feature/ --stop-on-failure'
      }
      post {
        always {
          sh '/usr/bin/php artisan mysql:deletedb $GIT_COMMIT_SHORT'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea on how to deal with it would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests that you're trying to access the request before it's been bound to the service container. This would happen if you're using the `request()` helper or `Request` facade before a request has been passed to the Http Kernel.

Is it possible that you added new code that may be trying to access the request in your tests before you've run `$this->get()` or any other HTTP helper method?

In Laravel 7, [this is where `"request"` is bound to the container](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/88dd075b9f1beaff93796a0ee51818796ca04654/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php#L131) and [this is where the container is failing](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/88dd075b9f1beaff93796a0ee51818796ca04654/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L808-L812) (based on your error message). This means that the container is trying to resolve `request` as a class instead of use an instance that's already been bound to that name.

Comment: but if that was the case shouldn't this errror happen on local too? Because it only happens inside Jenkins

Comment: @CesarVinicius what step does the error appear in? Also, you can try adding `-v` to all your artisan command steps to get a full stack trace, which should help you hunt it down.

Comment: at the end of tests. Ty to check this https://freeimage.host/i/1vlvl2